# MySQL select value X times based on number in another column

Tags: mysql, select, repeat

I need your help in this case. I have this **records** table:

```
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+------------+
| record_id | record | number_repeats | counter | sort_order |
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+------------+
|         1 | Value3 |              2 |      0  |          3 |
|         2 | Value2 |              1 |      0  |          2 |
|         3 | Value1 |              3 |      0  |          1 |
|         4 | Value4 |              1 |      0  |          4 |
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+------------+
```

I have this simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY sort_order
```

After sorting I need to select *Value1* and to update value in column **counter** so after that table will have this look:

```
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+------------+
| record_id | record | number_repeats | counter | sort_order |
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+------------+
|         3 | Value1 |              3 |       1 |          1 |
|         2 | Value2 |              1 |       0 |          2 |
|         1 | Value3 |              2 |       0 |          3 |
|         4 | Value4 |              1 |       0 |          4 |
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+------------+
```

After next query number in column **counter** will be *2* and so on. When number in column **counter** equals number from column **number_repeats** I need to select *Value2* and so on.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update my_table set counter = counter +1 where record = 'value1'

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the comment. I know how to increment value but I don't know what should I do when "number_repeats" == "counter". For example something like this:
`SELECT record FROM records WHERE number_repeats != counter ORDER BY sort_order LIMIT 1`

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the problem

Comment: OK, let me explain what I want to achieve. I have form on my page and when user submit data I need to select record based on columns **sort_order** then on **counter** and finally on **number_repeats**.
So, when user first time submit data I'm looking for _Value1_: `SELECT record FROM records WHERE counter != number_repeats ORDER BY sort_order LIMIT 1` I increment counter value: `UPDATE records SET counter = counter+1 WHERE record='Value1'`.
When next user submit data I repeat that query and so on. First three users have _Value1_ and fourth have _Value2_ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Update my_table set counter = counter +1 where counter < repeats order by sort_order limit 1;
```